# Flutter ListView.Builder Scroll Is Partial Working

Tags: flutter, listview, listviewitem

I'm developing application in flutter and I'm trying to make a list view with scrolling vertical option but it doesn't work for me like I want....
If any one can help me I will appreciate it!

**This is my code:**

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 00.0, vertical: 200.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: 275,
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        primary: true,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: displayList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              onTap: () {},
                              title: Text(displayList[index].toString()),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ))
                ],
              )),
```

When I'm trying to scroll down the list you can see that I am able to scroll the list just by holding the left side of the listview's card list tile but i want to scroll from each position of the list view....

**my problem pic :**

[My Problem... when holding this position i am able to scroll the listview...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJEqV.png)

**what i want it to be :**

[what i want it to be.. i want to hold somewhere in this position and be able to scroll the listview down......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUmI3.png)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping only the Card with the Text inside, instead of using ListTile?

Comment: Still doesn't work ... And also I'm using ListTile because i want to know when list's item is pressed....

Comment: I tried your code in dartpad i can scroll from any where there is no problem also you don't need specify  `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,`@kickass213

Comment: think I found your problem...remove the maxHeight constraint and try again please

Comment: no also doesn't work..... maybe something else is the problem and not this code maybe something before is doing this problem no ?

Comment: Ok I have found the problem thank you very much ! it needed to fix the size of other container ....